# How to shim System.Environment?

Tags: .net-4.5, visual-studio-2019, shim

I am trying to shim System.Environment:

```
Dim args = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e")}
System.Fakes.ShimEnvironment.GetCommandLineArgsGet =
Function() As String()
   Return args
End Function
```

I have a reference to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.dll

and I have the following files in the Fakes folder of my project:

mscorlib.fakes:

```
<Fakes xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/fakes/2011/">
  <Assembly Name="mscorlib" Version="4.0.0.0"/>
</Fakes>
```

System.fakes:

```
<Fakes xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/fakes/2011/">
  <Assembly Name="System" Version="4.0.0.0"/>
</Fakes>
```

However I get the compilation error:

> error BC30456: 'ShimEnvironment' is not a member of 'System.Fakes'.

How can I shim System.Environment?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b49e9f5d-0e57-46b1-8ced-f3231db5e813/cannot-find-a-shim-for-systemenvironmentmachinename-etc?forum=vsunittest I had to put the following to mscorlib.fakes:

```
  <ShimGeneration>
    <Add FullName="System.Environment"/>
  </ShimGeneration>
```